# i can't convert this json to pojo (java Class)

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

i can not convert this json to java class, i have problem by "value" in this json file, value in some position is array and some positions jost key value!!
i work with IntelliJ and and it is my error :

```
2017-09-18 14:43:21.540  WARN 5496 --- [apr-8080-exec-2]  .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of com.ada.bean.response.Issue out of START_ARRAY token
```

at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.ada.bean.response.Issue out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]

this is my json:

```
[
{
"id": "ETC-1",
"entityId": "94-5024",
"jiraId": null,
"field": [
  {
    "name": "projectShortName",
    "value": "ETC"
  },
  {
    "name": "numberInProject",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "summary",
    "value": "????? API ??? Youtrack ? ????? ?? ??"
  },
  {
    "name": "created",
    "value": "1504079347372"
  },
  {
    "name": "updated",
    "value": "1504341622265"
  },
  {
    "name": "updaterName",
    "value": "a.fathizade"
  },
  {
    "name": "updaterFullName",
    "value": "Ali Fathizadeh"
  },
  {
    "name": "resolved",
    "value": "1504341622257"
  },
  {
    "name": "reporterName",
    "value": "v.sabeti"
  },
  {
    "name": "reporterFullName",
    "value": "???? ?????"
  },
  {
    "name": "commentsCount",
    "value": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "votes",
    "value": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "Priority",
    "value": [
      "Normal"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Normal"
    ],
    "color": {
      "bg": "#e6f6cf",
      "fg": "#4da400"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Type",
    "value": [
      "Task"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Task"
    ],
    "color": null
  },
  {
    "name": "State",
    "value":  [
      "Fixed"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Fixed"
    ],
    "color": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Assignee",
    "value": [
      {
        "value": "a.fathizade",
        "fullName": "Ali Fathizadeh"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Subsystem",
    "value": [
      "Employees"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Employees"
    ],
    "color": {
      "bg": "#ff7123",
      "fg": "#fff"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "sprint",
    "value": [
      {
        "value": "First sprint",
        "id": "Etc Board:First sprint"
      }
    ]
  }
],
"comment": [],
"tag": []
},
{
"id": "ETC-2",
"entityId": "94-5026",
"jiraId": null,
"field": [
  {
    "name": "projectShortName",
    "value": "ETC"
  },
  {
    "name": "numberInProject",
    "value": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "summary",
    "value": "???? ?????? ???? ? ??? ??? ????"
  },
  {
    "name": "created",
    "value": "1504079557400"
  },
  {
    "name": "updated",
    "value": "1504341630002"
  },
  {
    "name": "updaterName",
    "value": "a.fathizade"
  },
  {
    "name": "updaterFullName",
    "value": "Ali Fathizadeh"
  },
  {
    "name": "resolved",
    "value": "1504341629992"
  },
  {
    "name": "reporterName",
    "value": "v.sabeti"
  },
  {
    "name": "reporterFullName",
    "value": "???? ?????"
  },
  {
    "name": "commentsCount",
    "value": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "votes",
    "value": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "Priority",
    "value": [
      "Normal"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Normal"
    ],
    "color": {
      "bg": "#e6f6cf",
      "fg": "#4da400"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Type",
    "value": [
      "Task"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Task"
    ],
    "color": null
  },
  {
    "name": "State",
    "value": [
      "Fixed"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Fixed"
    ],
    "color": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Assignee",
    "value": [
      {
        "value": "a.fathizade",
        "fullName": "Ali Fathizadeh"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Subsystem",
    "value": [
      "Employees"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Employees"
    ],
    "color": {
      "bg": "#ff7123",
      "fg": "#fff"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "sprint",
    "value": [
      {
        "value": "First sprint",
        "id": "Etc Board:First sprint"
      }
    ]
  }
 ],
 "comment": [],
 "tag": []
 },
 {
"id": "ETC-4",
"entityId": "94-5030",
"jiraId": null,
"field": [
  {
    "name": "projectShortName",
    "value": "ETC"
  },
  {
    "name": "numberInProject",
    "value": "4"
  },
  {
    "name": "summary",
    "value": "????? ??????? ???? ?? Youtrack ? ????? ?? ?? ?????? ????"
  },
  {
    "name": "created",
    "value": "1504079626044"
  },
  {
    "name": "updated",
    "value": "1504341630988"
  },
  {
    "name": "updaterName",
    "value": "a.fathizade"
  },
  {
    "name": "updaterFullName",
    "value": "Ali Fathizadeh"
  },
  {
    "name": "reporterName",
    "value": "v.sabeti"
  },
  {
    "name": "reporterFullName",
    "value": "???? ?????"
  },
  {
    "name": "commentsCount",
    "value": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "votes",
    "value": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "Priority",
    "value": [
      "Normal"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Normal"
    ],
    "color": {
      "bg": "#e6f6cf",
      "fg": "#4da400"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Type",
    "value": [
      "Task"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Task"
    ],
    "color": null
  },
  {
    "name": "State",
    "value": [
      "In Progress"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "In Progress"
    ],
    "color": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Assignee",
     "value": [
       {
        "value": "a.fathizade",
        "fullName": "Ali Fathizadeh"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Subsystem",
    "value": [
      "Employees"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Employees"
    ],
    "color": {
      "bg": "#ff7123",
      "fg": "#fff"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "sprint",
    "value": [
      {
        "value": "First sprint",
        "id": "Etc Board:First sprint"
      }
    ]
  }
],
"comment": [],
"tag": []
},
{
"id": "ETC-5",
"entityId": "94-5032",
"jiraId": null,
"field": [
  {
    "name": "projectShortName",
    "value": "ETC"
  },
  {
    "name": "numberInProject",
    "value": "5"
  },
  {
    "name": "summary",
    "value": "Parse ???? ??????? ???? Excel ????????"
  },
  {
    "name": "created",
    "value": "1504079740110"
  },
  {
    "name": "updated",
    "value": "1505302061947"
  },
  {
    "name": "updaterName",
    "value": "a.fathizade"
  },
  {
    "name": "updaterFullName",
    "value": "Ali Fathizadeh"
  },
  {
    "name": "resolved",
    "value": "1505302061939"
  },
  {
    "name": "reporterName",
    "value": "v.sabeti"
  },
  {
    "name": "reporterFullName",
    "value": "???? ?????"
  },
  {
    "name": "commentsCount",
    "value": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "votes",
    "value": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "Priority",
    "value": [
      "Normal"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Normal"
    ],
    "color": {
      "bg": "#e6f6cf",
      "fg": "#4da400"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Type",
    "value": [
      "Task"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Task"
    ],
    "color": null
  },
  {
    "name": "State",
    "value": [
      "Fixed"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Fixed"
    ],
    "color": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Assignee",
    "value": [
      {
        "value": "a.fathizade",
        "fullName": "Ali Fathizadeh"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Subsystem",
    "value": [
      "Employees"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Employees"
    ],
    "color": {
      "bg": "#ff7123",
      "fg": "#fff"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "sprint",
    "value": [
      {
        "value": "First sprint",
        "id": "Etc Board:First sprint"
      }
    ]
  }
 ],
 "comment": [],
 "tag": []
 },
 {
"id": "ETC-6",
"entityId": "94-5034",
"jiraId": null,
"field": [
  {
    "name": "projectShortName",
    "value": "ETC"
  },
  {
    "name": "numberInProject",
    "value": "6"
  },
  {
    "name": "summary",
      "value": "????? ??????? Youtrack ????? ?? DB ?? ??????? ???"        
  },
  {
    "name": "description",
    "value": "????? ??????? ??? ??? ?? ???? ?????"
  },
  {
    "name": "created",
    "value": "1504079823857"
  },
  {
    "name": "updated",
    "value": "1504079836355"
  },
  {
    "name": "updaterName",
    "value": "v.sabeti"
  },
  {
    "name": "updaterFullName",
    "value": "???? ?????"
  },
  {
    "name": "reporterName",
    "value": "v.sabeti"
  },
  {
    "name": "reporterFullName",
    "value": "???? ?????"
  },
  {
    "name": "commentsCount",
    "value": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "votes",
    "value": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "Priority",
    "value": [
      "Normal"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Normal"
    ],
    "color": {
      "bg": "#e6f6cf",
      "fg": "#4da400"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Type",
    "value": [
      "Task"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Task"
    ],
    "color": null
  },
  {
    "name": "State",
    "value": [
      "Open"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Open"
    ],
    "color": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Assignee",
    "value": [
      {
        "value": "a.fathizade",
        "fullName": "Ali Fathizadeh"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Subsystem",
    "value": [
      "Employees"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Employees"
    ],
    "color": {
      "bg": "#ff7123",
      "fg": "#fff"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "sprint",
    "value": [
      {
        "value": "First sprint",
        "id": "Etc Board:First sprint"
      }
    ]
  }
],
"comment": [],
"tag": []
 },
{
"id": "ETC-7",
"entityId": "94-5036",
"jiraId": null,
"field": [
  {
    "name": "projectShortName",
    "value": "ETC"
  },
  {
    "name": "numberInProject",
    "value": "7"
  },
  {
    "name": "summary",
    "value": "????????? ?? ????? ?????? ? ????? ?? ?? ??? ??????"
  },
  {
    "name": "created",
    "value": "1504079868785"
  },
  {
    "name": "updated",
    "value": "1504079868785"
  },
  {
    "name": "updaterName",
    "value": "v.sabeti"
  },
  {
    "name": "updaterFullName",
    "value": "???? ?????"
  },
  {
    "name": "reporterName",
    "value": "v.sabeti"
  },
  {
    "name": "reporterFullName",
    "value": "???? ?????"
  },
  {
    "name": "commentsCount",
    "value": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "votes",
    "value": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "Priority",
    "value": [
      "Normal"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Normal"
    ],
    "color": {
      "bg": "#e6f6cf",
      "fg": "#4da400"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Type",
    "value": [
      "Task"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Task"
    ],
    "color": null
  },
  {
    "name": "State",
    "value": [
      "Open"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Open"
    ],
    "color": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Assignee",
    "value": [
      {
        "value": "a.fathizade",
        "fullName": "Ali Fathizadeh"
      }
    ]
    },
    {
    "name": "Subsystem",
    "value": [
      "Employees"
    ],
    "valueId": [
      "Employees"
    ],
    "color": {
      "bg": "#ff7123",
      "fg": "#fff"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "sprint",
    "value": [
      {
        "value": "First sprint",
        "id": "Etc Board:First sprint"
      }
    ]
  }
],
"comment": [],
"tag": []
}
]
```

and this are classes that i write for this json:
Issues:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Issues implements Serializable
{
@JsonProperty
private Issue[] issue;

public Issue[] getIssue ()
{
    return issue;
}

public void setIssue (Issue[] issue)
{
    this.issue = issue;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [issue = "+issue+"]";
}
}
```

Issue:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Issue implements Serializable
{

@JsonProperty
private String id;

@JsonProperty
private Field [] field;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Field[] getField() {
    return field;
}

public void setField(Field[] field) {
    this.field = field;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Issue{" +
            "id='" + id + '\'' +
            ", field=" + Arrays.toString(field) +
            '}';
 }
 }
```

Field:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Field implements Serializable {


@JsonProperty
private String name;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Field{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
//                ", value='" + value + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your "root" Entity is kind of an Array (as the exception message says), (as far as I know,) the Jackson Mapper uses methods inherited from Collection.
So the fastest and easiest way is to inherit methods from a Collection implementation, e.g. ArrayList:

```
...
public class Issues extends ArrayList<Issue> {

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ClassPojo [issue = " + super.toString() +  "]";
 }
```

}

Note that you don't need the "issue" Attribute anymore, the array is stored internally by the List implementation.
The sample above works for me, called from the com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper (whereby getJson() returns exactly the String you provided):

```
ObjectMapper mapperObj = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        Issues li = mapperObj.readValue(getJson(),Issues.class);
        System.out.println(li);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output:

```
ClassPojo [issue = [Issue{id='ETC-1', field=[Field{name='projectShortName'}, Field{name='numberInProject'}, Field{name='summary'}, Field{name='created'}, Field{name='updated'}, Field{name='updaterName'}, Field{name='updaterFullName'}, Field{name='resolved'}, Field{name='reporterName'}, Field{name='reporterFullName'}, Field{name='commentsCount'}, Field{name='votes'}, Field{name='Priority'}, Field{name='Type'}, Field{name='State'}, Field{name='Assignee'}, Field{name='Subsystem'}, Field{name='sprint'}]}, Issue{id='ETC-2', field=[Field{name='projectShortName'}, Field{name='numberInProject'}, Field{name='summary'}, Field{name='created'}, Field{name='updated'}, Field{name='updaterName'}, Field{name='updaterFullName'}, Field{name='resolved'}, Field{name='reporterName'}, Field{name='reporterFullName'}, Field{name='commentsCount'}, Field{name='votes'}, Field{name='Priority'}, Field{name='Type'}, Field{name='State'}, Field{name='Assignee'}, Field{name='Subsystem'}, Field{name='sprint'}]}, Issue{id='ETC-4', field=[Field{name='projectShortName'}, Field{name='numberInProject'}, Field{name='summary'}, Field{name='created'}, Field{name='updated'}, Field{name='updaterName'}, Field{name='updaterFullName'}, Field{name='reporterName'}, Field{name='reporterFullName'}, Field{name='commentsCount'}, Field{name='votes'}, Field{name='Priority'}, Field{name='Type'}, Field{name='State'}, Field{name='Assignee'}, Field{name='Subsystem'}, Field{name='sprint'}]}, Issue{id='ETC-5', field=[Field{name='projectShortName'}, Field{name='numberInProject'}, Field{name='summary'}, Field{name='created'}, Field{name='updated'}, Field{name='updaterName'}, Field{name='updaterFullName'}, Field{name='resolved'}, Field{name='reporterName'}, Field{name='reporterFullName'}, Field{name='commentsCount'}, Field{name='votes'}, Field{name='Priority'}, Field{name='Type'}, Field{name='State'}, Field{name='Assignee'}, Field{name='Subsystem'}, Field{name='sprint'}]}, Issue{id='ETC-6', field=[Field{name='projectShortName'}, Field{name='numberInProject'}, Field{name='summary'}, Field{name='description'}, Field{name='created'}, Field{name='updated'}, Field{name='updaterName'}, Field{name='updaterFullName'}, Field{name='reporterName'}, Field{name='reporterFullName'}, Field{name='commentsCount'}, Field{name='votes'}, Field{name='Priority'}, Field{name='Type'}, Field{name='State'}, Field{name='Assignee'}, Field{name='Subsystem'}, Field{name='sprint'}]}, Issue{id='ETC-7', field=[Field{name='projectShortName'}, Field{name='numberInProject'}, Field{name='summary'}, Field{name='created'}, Field{name='updated'}, Field{name='updaterName'}, Field{name='updaterFullName'}, Field{name='reporterName'}, Field{name='reporterFullName'}, Field{name='commentsCount'}, Field{name='votes'}, Field{name='Priority'}, Field{name='Type'}, Field{name='State'}, Field{name='Assignee'}, Field{name='Subsystem'}, Field{name='sprint'}]}]]
```